Show that these two rank $1$ perturbations have the same eigenvectors
problem:let $D=diag(d_1,d_2,...,d_n)$, if $D+\alpha uu^T$ and $D+\hat{u}\hat{u}^T$ has the same set of eigenvalues, let these eigenvalues be $\lambda_1, \lambda_2,...,\lambda_n$, and satisfy $\lambda_1>d_1>\lambda_2>d_2>...>\lambda_n>d_n$, then they have the same set of eigenvectors
my attempt:
from my textbook we have the following lemma, that is

lemma1:(Lowner) let $D=diag(d_1,d_2,..,d_n)$ satisfy $d_1>d_2>...>d_n$, if $\hat{D}=D+\hat{u} \hat{u}^T$ have eigenvalues
$\lambda_i$ such that
$$\lambda_1>d_1>\lambda_2>d_2>...>\lambda_n>d_n$$then $$ \left|\hat{u}_i\right|=\left(\frac{\prod_{k=1}^n\left(\lambda_k-d_i\right)}{\prod_{k=1,
> k \neq i}^n\left(d_k-d_i\right)}\right)^{1 / 2} $$

and also we have

lemma2
let $D=diag(d_1,d_2,...,d_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is diagonal, $u \in \mathbb{R}^n, \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, if $\lambda$ is
the eigenvalues of $D+\alpha u u^{\top}$ , and $\lambda \neq d_i$,
$i=1,2, \ldots, n$, then $(D-\lambda I)^{-1} u$ is the corresponding
eigenvectors

then I don't know how to proceed, I konw $uu^T$ is projection onto $u$, then what should we do
